# Error adding 'data'-tag when calling web-service from PowerShell

Tags: python, rest, web-services, powershell

I have the below web-service request written in Python, but need to convert it to PowerShell in order to deploy it on our production environment.

Somehow I can't seem to get the data-part of the call working (so it will not authenticate me). It it working fine from Python, but what should the syntax be for PowerShell

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.post("http://ws.issworld.com/SourceSystem/rest/json/usm/login", 
                           data='''{"userName":"JohnDoe", "password":"xxxxxxxxx"}''', 
                           headers={"Content-type": "application/json"})
if(not r.ok):
    print("Couldn't login.", str(r.status_code), str(r.headers), str(r.text))
    exit(1)
```

Any pointers will be welcome. I'm a newbie on both PowerShell and web-services.

Comment: Could you post the PowerShell code you've written so far?

Comment: It returns    


`Invoke-WebRequest : { "code" : 123, "message" : "Login failed for user null" } `

Comment: Sure @Persistent13  `$url = "ws.issworld.com/SourceSystem/rest/json/usm/login"; $username="JohnDoe"#($env:username), $password="xxxxxx"##$(throw "The 'password' parameter is required!") $usertag="username" $passtag="password" $body = @{$passtag = $password; $usertag = $username } $jsonbody=$body | ConvertTo-Json Write-Host $jsonbody Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Verbose -Body $jsonbody -ContentType "application/json"`

Comment: Solved  Parameter names are case sensitive `username` needed to be changed to `userName`